# How to add loop of .bak files to restore in single sscript?

Tags: sql-server

```
RESTORE DATABASE Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899
FROM DISK = 'E:\Restore\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1,
MOVE 'StatusBackup_Data' TO 'E:\Restore\Files\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.mdf',
MOVE 'StatusBackup_Log'  TO 'E:\Restore\Files\Status_backup_2015_05_31_230001_686899.ldf',
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1
GO
```

I have below script to restore database from backup. There are 9 more .bak files with date stamp

```
Status_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565
Status_backup_2015_09_31_230001_865643
Status_backup_2015_08_31_230012_967686
Status_backup_2015_07_31_230001_676760
Status_backup_2015_06_31_230001_665455
Status_backup_2015_04_31_230001_355656
Status_backup_2015_03_31_230001_246754
Status_backup_2015_02_31_230001_646457
Status_backup_2015_01_31_230001_975644
```

I need to include all these as a loop into above script. I am trying to add but did not get right script to include. please can anyone suggest me how to add remaining .bak files as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all of the other backup files log backups for the same database that you need to apply? Or are they supposed to be full backups and each one will be restored to its own database?

Comment: all are full backups and each one has to be restored on its own .mdf and .ldf files with timestamp into folder.

Answer (score 0):

Give this cursor-based approach a try:

```
CREATE TABLE #restoreFiles(
backupfile VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #restoreFiles (backupfile)
VALUES ('Status_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_09_31_230001_865643'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_08_31_230012_967686'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_07_31_230001_676760'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_06_31_230001_665455'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_04_31_230001_355656'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_03_31_230001_246754'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_02_31_230001_646457'),
         ('Status_backup_2015_01_31_230001_975644')

DECLARE @fileToRestore VARCHAR(100), @backupLocation varchar(500), @mdfLocation varchar(500), @ldfLocation varchar(500)

DECLARE restorecursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT backupfile FROM #restoreFiles

OPEN restorecursor

FETCH NEXT FROM restorecursor
INTO @fileToRestore

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @backupLocation = 'E:\Restore\' + @fileToRestore + '\' + @fileToRestore +'.bak'
    SET @mdfLocation = 'E:\Restore\Files\' + @fileToRestore + '.mdf'
    SET @ldfLocation = 'E:\Restore\Files\' + @fileToRestore + '.ldf'
    RESTORE DATABASE @fileToRestore
    FROM DISK = @backupLocation
    WITH  FILE = 1,
    MOVE 'StatusBackup_Data' TO @mdfLocation,
    MOVE 'StatusBackup_Log'  TO @ldfLocation,
    NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM restorecursor
    INTO @fileToRestore
END
CLOSE restorecursor
DEALLOCATE restorecursor
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add. all these .bak files are in their own folders. for eg: Status_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565.bak is in Status_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565 folder and Status_backup_2015_09_31_230001_865643 is in Status_backup_2015_09_31_230001_865643 folder and so on. can I use still the above code with cursor? Please let me know.

Comment: Just updated the answer to match the new requirement.

Comment: Thanks. when I executed query I got this below error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I think it's not liking the string construction in the restore part of the script. I just updated it, please try again.

Comment: executed query. showing 9 rows affected and below error message : Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
Cannot open backup device 'E:\RestoreStatus_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565\Status_backup_2015_10_31_230001_754565.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: So it sounds like that particular file may not exist... have you double-checked that?